How to select costmap layers in navigation plugins
Navigation2 provides plugins of costmap-layers for creating costmaps, such as Voxel Layer, Static Layer, Inflation Layer, Obstacle Layer.
What is the basis for the selection to create global costmap and local costmap?
For example, why choose the "static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer" plugins to generate global_costmap, and choose the "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer" plugins to generate local_costmap.

We have some tuning guide documentation that introduces the layers and what they do [1]. I think this does a good job for an introduction to why to use each layer at a functional level of detail. A bit more context can be seen in From the desks of ROS maintainers: A survey of modern & capable mobile robotics algorithms in the robot operating system 2. There's also a long heritage of 10+ years of Navigation that you can reference through threads, issues, configurations on other robots, etc.
[1] https://docs.nav2.org/tuning/index.html#costmap2d-plugins
[2] https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=MGZmVmwAAAAJ&citation_for_view=MGZmVmwAAAAJ:ULOm3_A8WrAC
